# Передача данных клиент-сервер Express, nodejs

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

пытаюсь передать данные с клиента на сервер, но не понимаю.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
        <form method="POST">
            <input type="text">
            <button id="button" type="submit">Нажми</button>
        </form>
        <div id="result"></div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
$("button").click(function(){
    jQuery.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
       url: "https://localhost:3000/",
       data: 'name=vasya',
       success: function (resp) {
           alert(resp);
       },
       error: function (xhr, str) {
           alert('Возникла ошибка: ' + xhr.responseCode);
       }
   });
})
```

NodeJs:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 3000;
const router = express.Router();

//const users = require(".path.js");

app.listen(port, (err) => {
    if (err) {
        return console.log('something bad happened', err)
    }
    console.log(`server is listening on ${port}`);
})

// app.get('/', function (req, res) {
//     res.send('Hello World!');
//   });

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

// GET method route
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.send('GET request to the homepage');
  });

  // POST method route
  app.post('/', function(req, res) {
    var name = req.body.name;
    console.log(name);
    res.send('Your name is ' + name);
});
```

Пока что пытаюсь передать хоть статическое значение, потом уже буду пытаться передать значение из input.
Подскажите, почему console.log(name) не выводится, я вообще не понимаю что происходит!!

Comment: У вас в урле `https`, но сервер явно слушает `http`

Comment: так мне пишет, что поддерживается только https

Comment: Кто пишет? Куда пишет? Что вообще происходит? Что в консоли браузера?

Comment: @AlexeyTen, вы решили мою проблему, вы гений!

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю, как это делать в связке с Express, но в нативном NodeJs, для POST-запроса,  необходимо подписываться на событие окончания передачи данных
https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v10.x/api/http.html#http_http_request_url_options_callback

```
let data = "";
req.on("data", chunk => {
  data += chunk;
});
req.on("end", () => {
 console.log(data)
});
```